# What is the newline character in the C language: \r or \n?

Tags: c, newline

What is the newline character in C? I know that different OS have different line-ending characters, but they get translated into the C newline character. What is that character?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It's `\n`. When you're reading or writing text mode files, or to stdin/stdout etc, you must use `\n`, and C will handle the translation for you. When you're dealing with binary files, by definition you are on your own.

Answer (score 18):

> What is the newline character in the C language: \r or \n?

The new-line may be thought of a *some* `char` and it has the value of `'\n'`.  C11 5.2.1

This C new-line comes up in 3 places: C source code, as a single `char` and as an end-of-line in file I/O when in *text* mode.

1. Many compilers will treat source text as ASCII.  In that case, codes 10, sometimes 13, and sometimes paired 13,10 as new-line for source code.  Had the source code been in another character set, different codes may be used.  This new-line typically marks the end of a line of source code (actually a bit more complicated here), // comment, and # directives.
2. In source code, the 2 characters `\` and `n` represent the `char` new-line as `\n`.  If ASCII is used,  this `char` would have the value of 10.
3. In file I/O, *in text mode*, upon reading the bytes of the input file (and stdin), *depending on the environment*, when bytes with the value(s)  of 10 (Unix), *13,10*, (*1) (Windows), 13 (Old Mac??) and other variations are translated in to a '\n'.  Upon writing a file (or stdout), the reverse translation occurs.
   Note: File I/O in binary mode makes no translation.

The `'\r'` in source code is the carriage return `char`.

(*1) A lone *13* and/or *10* may also translate into `\n`.

Answer (score 11):

If you mean by newline the **newline character** it is **\n** and **\r** is the **carrier return character**, but if you mean by newline the line ending then it depends on the operating system: DOS uses carriage return and line feed (**"\r\n"**) as a line ending, which Unix uses just line feed (**"\n"**)

Answer (score 5):

'\r' = carriage return and '\n' = line feed.

In fact, there are some different behaviors when you use them in different OSes. On Unix it is '\n', but it is '\r''\n' on Windows.

Comment: [Classic Mac OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_Mac_OS) also used **\r**, solely.