# Starting a new line of text in C

Tags: c, terminal

I only have about 1 week of experience in coding, so I've got a lot to learn. I am currently trying to finish an assignment I have in my C class where I have to write a script that can output `*`s all around the text Welcome to C Programming.

I have managed to complete the first part of the assignment with the code I wrote below, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the `*`s above and below the text. There wasn't anything mentioned in my notes or lectures either so I'm pretty lost at the moment.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{    
    printf ("** Welcome to C Programming **");    
    return 0;    
}
```

I work on a Mac if that helps. Thanks to anyone that can help me figure this out.

**Edit:** I added the new line tag and it's working now! Thank you everyone for your input. I am going to try practicing with all of the methods mentioned after I submit my assignment.

Comment: put `\n` in your string where you want the line breaks to happen. Does that give what you want?

Comment: It should be between quotes `" "`  for such escaped characters in order to have effect. (Use [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=new+line+c+programming&oq=newline+c+&gs_l=serp.3.0.0i19k1l3j0i22i10i30i19k1j0i22i30i19k1j0i22i10i30i19k1l2j0i22i30i19k1l3.1254084.1255221.0.1257284.10.9.0.0.0.0.239.904.0j5j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..4.6.901...0j0i67k1j0i131k1j0i10k1j0i10i67k1.YJ6-Fdt79Hk) or check  tutorials).

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス Er, Meninx, you know that ネ is *ne* not *ni*, right?

Comment: @TomZych It is translated as spelled not as written.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the newline character in the C language: \r or \n?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379848/what-is-the-newline-character-in-the-c-language-r-or-n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `'\n'` escape sequence to represent a newline (i.e. line-break) in your `printf` calls.  Since your IDE/code editor most likely uses a monospaced font it should be pretty easy to align the * characters properly:

```
printf ("******************************\n");    
printf ("** Welcome to C Programming **\n");    
printf ("******************************\n");
```

Or, if you wanted to put the whole thing in a single `printf` call, you can use the `\` character followed by a newline in a string literal to break the representation of the string in your editor over multiple lines:

```
printf (
"******************************\n \
** Welcome to C Programming **\n \
******************************\n"
);
```

Or even:

```
printf ("******************************\n" 
        "** Welcome to C Programming **\n"
        "******************************\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

As someone in the comments already mentioned - put the `\n` (new line character) in the text where you want a new line to occur.  E.G.

`printf("****\nWelcome to C Programming\n****")`;

```
****
Welcome to C Programming
****
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a character for that. It's called "newline". You can't put it directly in the string because that would create a new line in the source code, but inside quotes in C you can produce it with `\n`.

Alternatively, instead of `printf` you could use `puts`, which prints a new line after the string. For this special case this may even be a better solution, since you are not using any of `printf`'s features (the formatting).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    printf ("******************************\n");        
    printf ("** Welcome to C Programming **\n");    
    printf ("******************************\n");        
    return 0;    
}
```