# Possible contradiction in the definition of c-char in [lex.ccon]

Tags: c++, newline, language-lawyer

[[lex.ccon]](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.literal#lex.ccon) contains the following definition for *c-char*:

> *c-char*:
>         any member of the source character
>   set
>              except the
>   single-quote `’`, backslash `\`, or new-line character
>       *escape-sequence*
>       *universal-character-name*

Given that the [new-line character in `C` is the escape-sequence `\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18379848/1042389), isn't there a contradiction in the definition above?

PS: note that the C++ Standard doesn't really define what is a new-line character.

Comment: The C++ Standard also doesn't define what is a single-quote (instead it seems to imply that a Unicode Character 'RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+2019) is a single-quote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ Standard does say that the new-line characters are introduced for end-of-line indicators in [translation phase 1](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.phases#1.1), the source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens (A *character-literal* is a preprocessing token) and sequences of white-space characters (including comments) in [translation phase 3](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.phases#1.3), and each escape sequence (`\n` is a escape sequence) is converted to the corresponding member of the execution character set in [translation phase 5](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.phases#1.5).

So it is clearly defined that when forming a *character-literal*, the character sequence `\n` is not turned into a new-line character, and the end-of-line indicator (which, as well as all the details of translation phase 1, is implementation-defined, but it is generally agreed that the end-of-line indicator is LF on Unix and Unix-like systems, CR+LF on Windows) has already been turned into the new-line character.

Comment: It took me a while to really grasp what you wrote above. That was a great answer, and I totally agree with it. (+1).

Answer (score 6):

No, when the definition says "new-line character" it means an *actual* new-line, not the special two-character sequence (backslash and `n`) that can be interpreted by the compiler as a new-line in special circumstances (inside constant string or character literals).

Comment: Exactly:  It means you can't write `const char c = '` and then have the end of the line.  (Just as you can't write `const char c = ''';`)

Comment: `No, when the definition says "new-line character" it means an actual new-line` How do you know that? The standard doesn't define `new-line character`. What do you mean by `actual new-line`?

Comment: @JoãoAfonso The `new-line` in the standard is a new-line on the platform, it's not defined because it's supposed to be a known entity. In ASCII encoding it's the line-feed character, `0x0a`. In [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) it could be NL (`0x15`) or LF (`0x25`). It is whatever the constant character literal `'\n'` would be translated to for the current platform.

Comment: `The new-line in the standard is a new-line on the platform` Yes, the standard defines `new-line` as `the new-line character` [\[here\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp#1). So, I'm supposed to believe that the `new-line character` mentioned in the Standard is equivalent to the escape sequence `\n`, as far as C and C++ are concerned. And if that is the case, there is a contradiction in the definition of *c-char* shown above.

Comment: @JoãoAfonso Still no, a new-line character is a single character, the platform-specific new-line. The escape sequence `\n` is *two* characters, that when parsed by the compiler *results* in a single new-line character being stored. This is the reason the literal backslash \ and `n` in input is not a new-line. The backslash \ and the `n` is only special if read by the compiler at the time of compilation. There is no contradiction, there is no ambiguity. `new-line` and `\n` are two different things for the compiler.

Comment: @JoãoAfonso Also, `new-line` *is* defined in the specification, in [§16 Preprocessing directives](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp), as "the new-line character".