# how to read input until empty line in C

Tags: c

I am still a beginner to C. I am trying to write a program that reads input (test case) until an empty line is reached.

for example, input is the following:

```
2
1 2
2 5
3 6

2 3
1 7
```

the first number stands for the number of test cases. in the output there should be sums of the numbers on each line.
OUTPUT:

```
3
7
9

5
8
```

and there should be an empty line between them like in the example output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} A;

int main() {
    int n, i = 0;
    A nums[100];
    scanf("%d\n", &n);
    while(n--){
        while(empty line not reached){
            scanf("%d %d", &nums[i].a, &nums[i].b);
            i++;
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) printf("%d\n", nums[i].a + nums[i].b);
        printf("\n");
        i = 0;
            
    }
    return 0;
}
```

so what should I write there `while(empty line not reached)` how do I make the program detect the empty line and go to the next test case?

Comment: You can test an empty line with `fgets()` eg with `fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin); if (*line == '\n') /* deal with empty line */;`. I suggest you replace all your `scanf()` with `fgets()` and change the relevant code.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! that worked!! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the newline character in the C language: \r or \n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379848/what-is-the-newline-character-in-the-c-language-r-or-n)

Comment: @Andreas I have already solved it, thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Empty line has only one symbol.It is "new line" symbol. So you should look for two new lines symbols. If you work in non-binary mode with file you should look for \n\n symbols.